# Proving equivalence of nested path dependent types members

Tags: scala, dependent-type

This is a simplified case, and I am totally open to a different/better way to achieve this

```
trait Container {
  type T
  def data: List[T]
}

trait Transform {
  val from: Container
  val to: Container
  def xform: from.T => to.T
}

case class Identity(c: Container) extends Transform {
  val from = c
  val to = c
  def xform = { t: from.T => t }
}
```

This yields the predictable error of:

```
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : t.type (with underlying type Identity.this.from.T)
 required: Identity.this.to.T
         def xform = { t: from.T => t }
```

The goal is basically to have a transform which transforms objects underlying the container, but to be able to convince the type checker (without horrible horrible casts all over the place) that the types are the same.

What is the best way to be able to show equivalences and relationships of types in this way?

Like I said, totally open to restructuring the code and I promise in the actual example it is for a real purpose :)

Comment: Are you open to adding _any_ type parameters? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think generic parameters might be an easier way to describe this pattern.

You can avoid the generic parameter all together, however, by explicitly identifying the type `T` on both the `Container` instances:

```
case class Identity(c: Container) extends Transform {
  val from: Container { type T = c.T } = c
  val to: Container { type T = c.T } = c
  def xform = { t: from.T => t }
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
case class Identity(c: Container) extends Transform {
  val from: c.type = c
  val to: c.type = c
  def xform = { t: from.T => t }
}
```

If you're OK with only avoiding the generic parameters on `Container` and `Transform`, you can convince the compiler that the types works by doing:

```
case class Identity[U](c: Container { type T = U }) extends Transform {
  val from = c
  val to = c
  def xform = { t: c.T => t }
}
```

The generic parameter `U` does nothing other than give another name to the `T` type on the `Container` parameter, but that is enough to do the trick!

To me, all these solutions really just underscore how seemingly arbitrary the power of the type checker is when it comes to these sorts of types.  I can't really explain why they are necessary or sufficient.  In my experience, it is much more predictable to work with generic parameters (although of course it can be much messier).

Comment: Thanks! And you're totally right about how arbitrary the type checker can feel. I think it comes down to equivalence being undecidable in many contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Because the type in `Container` isn't exposed, you can't infer anything about the `Identity` class. Think about if you were using this from another library, there's no way to know what type `xform` is if you're just given and `Identity` object. Really, the only definition that you could use for `xform` is something like:

```
def xform = { t: from.T => to.data.head }
```

And the only way you could call would be with `from.data.head`.

An alternative is to drop path dependent types and use higher kinded types:

```
  trait Container[T] {
    def data: List[T]
  }

  trait Transform[A, B] {
    val from: Container[A]
    val to: Container[B]
    def xform: A => B
  }

  case class Identity[A](c: Container[A]) extends Transform[A, A] {
    val from = c
    val to = c
    def xform = { t: A => t }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If one is ever stuck with dependent types, structural refinement is an ugly but effective bail-out.

```
abstract class ContainerRefiner {
  val container: Container
}

trait Container {
  type T
  def data: List[T]
}

trait Transform {
  val from: Container
  val to: Container
  def xform: from.T => to.T
}

case class Identity(c: Container) extends Transform {
  val refiner = new {val container: c.type = c} with ContainerRefiner
  val from = refiner.container
  val to = refiner.container
  def xform = { t: from.T => t }
}
```

Can anyone please comment on the pros and cons between this approach and higher kinded types?